# Prevent labels being cut off / clipped at edge of map

Tags: qgis, labeling

I've read a few other issues about trying to prevent labels from rendering if they run off the edge of the map canvas. This is particularly a problem in Composer, where I get lots of country labels which are only half on the page.

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/10314

In the above post in the QGIS issue queue, Nyall Dawson says "There's an option in the global label settings to prevent clipped labels at the edge of maps".

I can't find this setting. Does anyone know where it is? Or any other solution for this problem?

Comment: And how about an option to bypass the settings to prevent label to be cut off? I need every labels but within the canvas

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's how to access that setting. First open the layer properties by double clicking a layer, then go to the labeling tab. Look for the button in the top-right of the window (shown below):

[image]

Then, switch off "show partial labels":

[image]

This setting applies to all labelled layers in your project.