# Layer labels not showing properly on the composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I'm currently working on a map for the different brazilian biomes.

[image: Here's the map on the standard QGIS view] I have to label them and show it on my final map, but when I'm working on the composer, this happens:

[image: Nope, I didn't crop it wrong.]

That's the exact size of my map. If you take a close look, you'll see that the "CERRADO" word appears cut in the middle on the upper- left side. I've looked around and found a pretty similar situation [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/qgis-2-2-prevent-labels-being-cut-off-clipped-at-edge-of-map) but the solution proposed doesn't apply. It still displays like the second picture. I need all three labels to be inside the map window I created on the composer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the map rotated?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have this map and other two (the squares on the image above) which are also rotated.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately the option to prevent cut-off labels doesn't play nicely with rotated maps (in other words - it doesn't work at all!). I've hit this same issue on maps I've created.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this settings in your labelling options.

[image]

Or perhaps, you could check the map canvass and composer have the same rotation.

Comment: My labels have the exact same settings since I posted this question (I'll add a picture there)  and no rotation has been applied to the labels. If I do so, they appear rotated on the final map, which is not what I desire.