# Prevent labels being cut off at edge when using Layout-Atlas

Tags: qgis-3

Im creating an atlas but the labels on the edges sometimes get cut off:

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

The text is coming from a Point layer, and the Point is located at the "E" letter above. I know of this question: [Prevent labels being cut off / clipped at edge of map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/prevent-labels-being-cut-off-clipped-at-edge-of-map), but the solution is to not draw "Ekebäckshult" at all.

How can I make the labels draw correctly on the edges?

Comment: One possible way is to anchor the the label position of that point to number `7` using `Offset from point` and reduce the font size for the same label, because the label font size is bigger than the available space.

Comment: I would need to find some way of doing this automatically since i have many labels and edges.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try setting a margin to 10% under **Controlled by Atlas** tab and then increase the size of your print composer by 10% so that the scale of your map will remain the same and you'll get overlapping tiles when you export.

[image: Controlled by atlas tab]

2. Export the atlas.
3. Split your atlas polygon into separate files with `Split layer` in QGIS. (This function creates geopackage files)
4. Clip your atlas rasters with `gdalwarp -crop_to_cutline -cutline tile_1.gpkg output_1.tif output_1_clip.tif`and if you have many of these you could make a small shell script like this to batch this clipping if you have 10 tiles:

---

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    gdalwarp -crop_to_cutline -cutline page_${i}.gpkg output_${i}.tif output_${i}_clip.tif
done
```